# which size of chunk will yield to best performance using master-worker with MPI?

Tags: c, load-balancing, parallel-processing, mpi, master-slave

Im using MPI to parrlel a program that is trying to solve the Metric TSP problem. I have P processors , and N cities to pass .

Each thread asks for work from the master, recieves a chunk - which is a range of permutation that he should check and calculates the minimal among them. I am optimizing this by pruning bad routes in advance.

There are total (N-1)! routes to calculate. each worker get a chunk with a number that represnt the first route he has to check and the also the last. In addition the master sends him the most recent best result known , so can easly prone bad routes in advance with some lower bound on thier remains.

Each time a worker is finding result that is better that the global , he asyncrounsly sends it to the all other workers and to the master.

Im not looking for better solution- I'm just trying to determine which chunk size is the best.

The best chunk size i've found so far is  (n!)/(n/2)!  , but it doesnt yield so good result .

please help me understand which chunk size is the best here. I'm trying to balance between the amount of computation and communication
thanks

Comment: This ratio also depends on the location of the master/slaves __and the amount of work that has to be done__. If it's a small request by a user that must be finished in less then a second there is much more emphasis on reducing the communication then when you are pre-calculating a lot of routes (then there is a lot of communication time available).

Comment: They are thread in the same system which contains 2 cores and each cores has 4 threads. But , i dont know in advance how many threads the system supplies me. The performance requierment is to run less than 10 minutes on N<=18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends heavily on factors beyond your control: MPI implementation, total load on the machine, etc. However, I'd hazard a guess that it also heavily depends on how many worker processes there are. On that note, understand that MPI spawns processes, not threads.

Ultimately, as is often the case with most optimization questions, the answer is simply "test a lot of different settings and see which one is best". You may want to do this manually, or write a tester app that implements some sort of heuristic (e.g. a genetic algorithm).

Comment: which size of chunks you recommend me to check ?

Comment: Let's see: chunk size may vary from 1 all the way up to (N-1)! / P, which is of the magnitude 10^14 when N=18. That's a huge space that's impossible to thoroughly test within reasonable time. I'd start with N around 6-8 and various values of P, test about 100 chunk sizes from this entire range, and see which ones produce the best results. Then I'd increase N and only focus on chunk sizes roughly in the range that produced tolerable results for the lower N. I just came up with this on the spot though, so it may or may not be a good idea.